# sbt 0.13.1 multi-project module not found when I change the sbt default scala library to scala 2.11.2

Tags: scala, sbt

I use the **sbt 0.13.1** create the two modules, and I create project/MyBuild.scala to compile this two modules. 
**MyBuild.scala:**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
object MyBuild extends Build {
    lazy val task = project.in(file("task"))
    lazy val root = project.in(file(".")) aggregate(task) dependsOn task
}
```

When I change the scala library to **2.11.2** by set **scalaHome**. It will go to maven download the **task.jar** and failed, that's very strange. Is it a sbt bug?

There is the github test project address: [test-sbt-0.13.1](https://github.com/chengpohi/test-sbt-0.13.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to move the sources of root project from root to subfolder (task2), and add them as aggregated. It will remove aggregating and depending on same project:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
          lazy val task = project.in(file("task"))
          lazy val task2 = project.in(file("task2")) dependsOn task
          lazy val root = project.in(file(".")) aggregate(task, task2) 
}
```

This works for me, but it's strange that such non-standard project structure works fine with default scalaHome. Seems to be a problem in the way in which sbt resolves such dependency as external.

P.S. This answer doesn't cover the whole story. See @jjst's answer to clarify more.

Comment: This probably works, but I don't think there's anything wrong or non-standard with just having a root project depending on a subproject. It's the approach recommended by [the sbt documentation for working with macro projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Macro-Projects.html) for example. See my answer below for a solution that keeps the same project structure.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have defined a custom `scalaVersion` in your main build.sbt which means it is defined for the root project only. The task project will use the default value:

```
jjst@ws11:test-sbt-0.13.1$ sbt                                                                                                                
[...]
> projects
[info] In file:/home/users/jjost/dev/test-sbt-0.13.1/
[info]   * root
[info]     task
> show scalaVersion
[info] task/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.10.4
[info] root/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.11.2-local
```

As a consequence, artifacts generated by the task subproject won't be available for the root project to use.

You can solve this by making sure that your projects use the same `scalaVersion`. The easiest way to do so while keeping the same project structure would be to share common settings like the scala version across projects like so:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
    val commonSettings = Seq(
      scalaVersion := "2.11.2-local",
      scalaHome := Some(file("/usr/local/scala-2.11.2/"))
    )

    lazy val task = (project.in(file("task"))).
    settings(commonSettings: _*)

    lazy val root = (project.in(file("."))).
    settings(commonSettings: _*).
    aggregate(task).
    dependsOn(task)
}
```

In practice, you might want to put common settings shared between projects in a dedicated file under `project/common.scala`, as recommended in [Effective sbt](http://jsuereth.com/scala/2013/06/11/effective-sbt.html).